# Generics and constructor in the inherited class

Tags: java, selenium, generics

guys. I am a QA tester and I keep learning automation with Selenium and Java. I can not understand why do I need to add generics and constructor in the class ProfilePage? 
So lets create Page Object class:

```
public class BasePageObject {

protected WebDriver driver; 

protected void getPage(String url){
    driver.get(url);

}

private WebElement find(By element) {
    return driver.findElement(element);
}   

protected void type(String text, By element){
    find(element).sendKeys(text);
} 
}
```

Now lets create class for profile page:

```
public class ProfilePage extends BasePageObject<ProfilePage> {

private By editProfileButton = By.xpath("//button[@id='editProfile']");
private By advancededitProfileButton = By.xpath("//a[@class='dice-btn-link']");
private By profileContactNameText = By.xpath("//h1[@class='profile-contact-name']");

protected ProfilePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}



public boolean isCorrectProfileLoaded(String correctProfileName){
    if (getText(profileContactNameText).equals(correctProfileName)){
    return true;
}else
    return false;
    } 
 }
```

So the question is: why should I use generics "ProfilePage" "after extends BasePageObject" and why do I have to create `protected ProfilePage(WebDriver driver) {
    super(driver);
}`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your doubts are justified. As far as seleniums `BasePageObject` is concerned, it has no type parameter and it has no constructor that would expect a `WebDriver` parameter.

Is it possible that there is another `BasePageObject` in a package other than `com.wikia.webdriver.pageobjectsfactory.pageobject` ?

If yes, then that's a reason. It's a bit confusing though.
Otherwise this `ProfilePage` just won't compile.

Comment: Yes!!! Thank you! I missed that I opened class  with the same name from another package!